# How does `brew uninstall <formula>` operate?

Tags: macos, homebrew

If I want to check what a brew formula does when `brew install <formula>` is run, I can open the formula code and look for the `def install` method.

**How can I know how `brew uninstall <formula>` operates?**

I checked [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook) but didn't find an explanation. Also, I don't see a `def uninstall` method in any package, so I suppose `brew uninstall` works in some general way, purging or unlinking files. I hope to find some way of understanding the exact steps run for any specific package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the behaviour of `brew uninstall` is not defined by the formula itself, but is generic. You can determine how it works by inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/9912dcab7c25b5aa90f4a1c73351e4213b90cf35/Library/Homebrew/keg.rb#L267):

```
  def uninstall(raise_failures: false)
    CacheStoreDatabase.use(:linkage) do |db|
      break unless db.created?

      LinkageCacheStore.new(path, db).delete!
    end

    path.rmtree
    path.parent.rmdir_if_possible
    remove_opt_record if optlinked?
    remove_linked_keg_record if linked?
    remove_old_aliases
    remove_oldname_opt_record
  rescue Errno::EACCES, Errno::ENOTEMPTY
    raise if raise_failures

    odie <<~EOS
      Could not remove #{name} keg! Do so manually:
        sudo rm -rf #{path}
    EOS
  end
```

Mainly all files in the formula directory are deleted and all links to the files belonging to the deleted formula are removed.